# report gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reporting, multi-tenant, apartment-gem

My team is creating a data management software in Rails using Apartment Gem for the individual customers (tenants).
We are looking for a reporting gem that supports multi tenancy.
Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Corina

Comment: Reporting is a very broad area, do you want to build dashboards, excel files, and not sure why multi-tenancy is really relevant. I would assume you report based on queries. But to start you could check here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting

Comment: many thanks for the suggestion we consider Apartment relevant because the tenants might have access limitations to the software based on their roles / permissions so we are looking at a dynamic reporting tool that picks up on the callbacks and give the users the relevant forms . i looked at reportskit and dossier combined with axlx or roo i think these are the best alternatives. We want both excel and Pdf .if you consider one of them better please do not hesitate to comment back. All the best Nathan!

Comment: I understand multi-tenancy is relevant, but I am afraid you will not find a reporting gem that will support that explicitly, as imho _any_ reporting gem will support that, as _you_ will be responsible for writing the queries to report on (and those have to take the multi-tenancy into account). Anyway, it sounds you had a good look already. Personally in general I use a more ad hoc approach: I do not use a gem like dossier or reportkit, bu I Use axlx to generate xls files, Nvd3 for charts and  phantom.js to convert my html-pages to pdf. All the best to you too, Corina! :)

Comment: your time to write these comments is highly appreciated Nathan thank you very much, we now have more clarity towards our strategy!